# Factory doesnt return http data response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Im trying to get http post data response using the code below (it is working).

```
app.factory('LoginService', function($http, $location) {

return {
    existUser: function(loginObj) 
    {

        $http({

            method: 'POST',
            url: server + '/login',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'},
            data: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(loginObj)

        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                return response.data;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log("erro!");

            }); 

    }
}

});
```

Inside of my controller, i have:

```
LoginService.existUser(loginObj).then(function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

And i got the error:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

What is wrong?

Comment: $http is returning success etc.

Comment: @Carsten i already changed to LoginService.existUser(loginObj).successCallback(function (data).... and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return response.data;` returns result of `then` function, not `existUser`! Modify your code like below:

```
app.factory('LoginService', function($http, $location) {

   return {
     existUser: function(loginObj) 
       {
          return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: server + '/login',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'},
            data: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(loginObj)
          })
       }
    }

});
```

In this case, `existUser` method returns promise object, that has `.then` method

Comment: OH! U rock bro! Thanks for the support! It works, but this factory has a lot of returns (at start "return {..", at $http "return $http..", inside of sucessCallback, inside of errorCallback) and looks like ugly... Do u have some tip to prevent it?

Comment: Use successCallback and errorCallback in controller. In factory all in all two returns.

Comment: existUser returns just object, that was created by $http constructor. No need to chain callbacks on it in return statement